# Drop down list in PHP page appearing blank

Tags: php

I have a drop down list that gathers the ocntents the directory which are Windows folders. Once a user chooses a value and clicks on Search, the results are the PDF files that are contained in that directory. As it turns out, I cannot find the reason why my drop down list results are blank. I have included my code as well as a screenshot of the blank drop down list. Curious enough, only one record appears in the drop down list which is a shortcut link. Please pardon my ignorance, I am a PHP newbie and the code is a bit messy. I am running the page on IIS 7.

```
<?php // CMM_Tino.php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

/**
* SEARCH FOR PDF FILES BASED ON DIRECTORY NAME
*/

// ACTIVATE THIS TO SHOW THE REQUEST
// var_dump($_GET);

function getFileList($dir) { 
// array to hold return value 
$retval = array();
// add trailing slash if missing 
 if(substr($dir, -1) != DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR) $dir .= DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
 // open pointer to directory and read list of files
 $d = @dir($dir) or die("getFileList: Failed opening directory $dir for reading");
 while(false !== ($entry = $d->read())) {
     // skip hidden files
     if($entry[0] == ".") continue; 
     if(is_dir("$dir$entry")) { 
         $retval[] = array( 
             "name" => "$dir$entry" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, 
             "type" => filetype("$dir$entry"), 
             "size" => 0, 
             "lastmod" => filemtime("$dir$entry") ); 
             } elseif(is_readable("$dir$entry")) { 
                 $retval[] = array( 
                     "filename" => "$entry", 
                     "filepath" => "$dir$entry"
                     );
                 }
             }
             $d->close();
         return $retval;
}
// LINKS TO THE PDF FILES, IF ANY
$links = NULL;

// PUT THE PATH TO THE DIRECTORY OF FILE FOLDERS HERE
$path  = './CMM_Search/CMM';

// GET THE LIST OF FILE FOLDERS
$folders = array_diff(scandir($path), array('.','..'));

// FILTER THE LIST OF FILE FOLDERS TO REMOVE EXTRANEOUS FILES
foreach ($folders as $key => $name)
{
if (!is_dir($path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $name)) unset($folders[$key]);
}

// IF THERE IS A REQUEST
$q = !empty($_GET['q']) ? $_GET['q'] : NULL;
if (!empty($q))
{
// IF THE REQUEST MATCHES ONE OF THE FILE FOLDERS
$folder = NULL;
foreach ($folders as $folder)
{
    if (strpos($folder, $q) !== FALSE) break;
    $folder = NULL;
}
if ($folder)
{
    $links = "<p><b>$folder</b></p>" . PHP_EOL;

    // GET THE LIST OF FILES IN THE FOLDER
     $files = array_diff(scandir($path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $folder),           array('.','..'));

    // PREPARE LINKS TO THE PDF FILES
    foreach ($files as $file)
    {
        $end = explode('.', $file);
        $end = end($end);
        $end = strtoupper($end);
        if ($end != 'PDF') continue;

        $links .= '<br>'
        . '<a target="my_pdf" '
        . 'href="'
        . $path
        . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
        . $folder
        . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
        . $file
        . '">'
        . $file
        . '</a>'
        . PHP_EOL
        ;
    }
}
else
{
    $links = '<br>'
    . 'Unknown Folder: '
    . "<b>$q</b>"
    . PHP_EOL
    ;
   }
}

// CREATE THE SEARCH PAGE USING PHP HEREDOC NOTATION
$htm = <<<EOD
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Barfield CMM Lookup</title>
<meta name="ROBOTS" content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW" />
<!-- CSS styles for standard search box -->
<style type="text/css">
#tfheader{
    background-color:#;
}
#tfnewsearch{
    float:center;
    padding:20px;
    width: 1686px;
}
.tftextinput{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    border:1px solid #0076a3; border-right:0px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px 5px;
}
.tfbutton {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    border: solid 1px #0076a3; border-right:0px;
    background: #0095cd;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#00adee),   to(#0078a5));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #00adee,  #0078a5);
    border-top-right-radius: 5px 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px 5px;
}
.tfbutton:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #007ead;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#0095cc), to(#00678e));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #0095cc,  #00678e);
}
/* Fixes submit button height problem in Firefox */
.tfbutton::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
}
.tfclear{
    clear:both;
}
.auto-style1 {
    width: 915px;
    height: 90px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
.auto-style2 {
    color: #0033CC;
}
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<!-- HTML for SEARCH BAR -->
<div id="tfheader">
    <br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <img alt="Barfield" class="auto-style1" src="Barfield.jpg" /><br /> 

<!-- ************** NOTE THE $links VARIABLE WILL BE FILLED IN BY THE PHP SCRIPT    ************** -->
$links
    <br />
<!-- ************** NOTE THE ACTION ATTRIBUTE IS REMOVED TO CAUSE THIS SCRIPT TO SEND  THE FORM REQUEST TO THE CURRENT URL ************** -->
    <form id="tfnewsearch" method="get">
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <span class="auto-style2"><strong>CMM</strong>              </span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <select class="tftextinput">
EOD;
            define('ROOT', getenv("DOCUMENT_ROOT") . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
            $res = getFileList(ROOT . 'CMM_Search' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'CMM' .      DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
            foreach ($res as $file){
              $htm .="<option>" . $file['filename'] . "</option>";
            }
$htm .= <<<EOD
            </select>
            <input type="submit" value="search"   class="tfbutton">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </form>
    <form id="tfnewsearch" method="get">
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <span class="auto-style2"><strong>ADDN DOCUMENTS</strong>   </span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="text" class="tftextinput" name="q" size="21"     maxlength="120"><input type="submit" value="search" class="tfbutton">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </form>
    <form id="tfnewsearch" method="get">
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <span class="auto-style2"><strong>PART NUMBER</strong>   </span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="text" class="tftextinput" name="q" size="21"    maxlength="120"><input type="submit" value="search" class="tfbutton">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </form>

    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='./QCJoe.jpg' width='200' height='200' /> Dev 1.1R1
```

EOD;

```
// WRITE THE HTML DOCUMENT TO THE BROWSER
echo $htm;
```

Comment: Could you edit this down to just the code that has the problem? It's hard to find it among all that `&nbsp;` junk.

Comment: try to put only a piece of your code and show your problem .

Comment: Thank you for the comments but if I knew the piece of code that was having the problem, I wouldn't be asking this particular question. The problem I am having is that I cannot find code that would be causing this problem. maybe i should have been more specific and state that i need help sifting through the code to find what may be causing the data not to appear in my drop downlist.